# change customer login url

Tags: magento, authentication, onchange

I want to change the customer login and account url

The current URL is http://www.example.com/customer/account/login/

I want To change with this http://www.example.nl/account/

I created a cms page and loaded login in that cms page it worked fine but it remain visible when the customer is logged in

```
$redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/');
$current_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if((!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) && ($current_url != $redirect_url)){
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your if statement is failing when checking if the customer is  logged in here:

```
...

    if((!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())

...
```

Try changing the code to below which will check the customers session to see if they are logged in:

```
    $redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/'); 
    $current_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); 
    if((!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) && ($current_url != $redirect_url)){ 
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url); }
```

I hope this helps.